# The metabase key '/lm/w3svc' could not be found

Tags: key, metabase

I have a laptop with Windows XP on it.
Trying to deploy an ASP.NET web application on IIS 6 I received the following error:

Error   1   Web deployment task failed.(The metabase key '/lm/w3svc' could not be found.)
The metabase key '/lm/w3svc' could not be found.
The metabase Admin Base Object could not be instantiated.  Perhaps the "IIS '6 Metabase Compatibility" feature is not installed.
Klasse is niet geregistreerd (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))

Installation of the IIS 6 Metabase compatibility feature on Windows XP is not available at
Control Panel, Administrative Tools,...
What about that metabase key '/lm/w3svc' ?
Thanks for your help?

Answer (score 1):

Windows XP only has IIS 5.1 if you install it through control panel.

This might be the reason.

/lm/w3svc is the base key in the IIS6 metabase which contains all the web sites that are registered in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error on windows 10, followed the instructions from Microsoft docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.2) and it has now been resolved.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).